# Product Image on category view not updated with new image

Tags: magento2

I am creating a module where the customer can design a product(saved programmatically), so each time he designs the product a new product image which is generated. But it is not updated in the category view page, but it is updated on the product view page. Upon research, I found that the images are loaded from the cache in the category page. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

As the user is re-designing the product( done programmatically in a module), it is impractical to clear cache or re-index from the admin side each time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Cache Management and scroll to the bottom of the page. Then click the Flush Catalog Images Cache button and the clear the other caches.

Or

You can run re-indexing : php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Hope this will help you! Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I read about this, but as the user is re-designing the product( done programmatically in a module), it is impractical to clear cache or re-index from the admin side each time.

Answer (score 0):

> **You can try below code For clearing cache and Re-indexing**
>
> You can call these functions `flushCache()`, `doReIndex()` wherever 
>   user is re-designing the product in a your module.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Version;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool;

class Operations
{
    protected $cacheTypeList;
    protected $cacheFrontendPool;
    protected $processor;

    public function __construct(
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
        \Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor $processor
    ) {
        $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    public function flushCache()
    {
        // Get all types of caches
        $_types = array_keys($this->cacheTypeList->getTypes());

        /*
         * It will return cache list array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
         */

        foreach ($_types as $type) {
            $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
        }
        foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
            $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
        }
    }

    public function doReIndex()
    {
        /* Regenerate indexes for all indexers */
        $this->processor->reindexAll();

        /* Regenerate indexes for all invalid indexers */
        $this->processor->reindexAllInvalid()
    }
}
```

> To flush the product image cache: From the Cache Storage Management
>   page, under Additional Cache Management, click Flush Catalog Images
>   Cache to clear pre-generated product image files.
>
> The Image cache was cleaned message appears at the top of the
>   workspace.
>
> Clear the cache of your browser.

[Check Magento Docs](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/cache-management.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply @MohitRane , Is there an option to flush the Magento2 Image cache?

Comment: Please check updated answer

Comment: accept the answer if it's solved your issue, so it could help others

Comment: No it didnt work

Comment: I've updated the code, please check now.

Comment: Hi thanks for the effort but it didn't work. Can you please check [link] (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281712/i-want-to-filter-the-products-listed-in-a-particular-category-page-by-an-attribu) and help me with this?

Comment: it's working solution.