# I want to filter the products, listed on a particular category page by an attribute value

Tags: magento2

I want to filter the product collection on a category page by the user_id of the current user. I have created an attribute 'user_id' which is linked to the product when it is created with the current id of the user(here products are created by the user). I have created a category 'User Products' also when directed to userproducts.html all the products are shown, I want to filter it by user_id of the current user.

Edit 1.
I tried overriding catalog_category_view in my module as suggested by @MohitRane but it is not loading from my module. This is the screenshot 
 [image]

Comment: Update your code such that it will be easy to debug..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following code,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_session;
    protected $_customerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_session = $session;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        if ($this->_session->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_session->getCustomer()->getId();
        }
    }
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $userId = $this->getCustomerId();
        if (!empty($userId)) {
            /*$customerCollection = $this->_customerFactory->create()
                                        ->getCollection()
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                                        ->load(); */

            $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                                    'user_id',
                                    array('eq' => $userId)
                                ); // user_id is your attribute name
            return $productCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

> Add `view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.products.list">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Test" name="my.block.name" template="Namespace_Modulename::product/list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> copy this `list.phtml` file from
>
> **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

**to**

> **view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

Comment: Where should I be calling getProductCollection(); ? I need to list these products in a page
Being new to Magento, excuse my level of knowledge

Comment: I did the above things in my module, but the list is not loading from my module. My module name is Faes_CCEngine.

Comment: Please check screenshots

Comment: okay i will look into it

Comment: Hi, any updates? @MohitRane